# How to withdraw KSM tokens from Karura without using the Karura Bridge graphical interface?

Tags: parachain, xcm, assets, bridge, karura

I transferred some KSM from the Kusama relay chain to the Karura parachain, and now I want to withdraw the tokens back to the relay chain.

That said, it seems that currently the Karura graphical interface is not working (down for meintenance) so I can't use the standard way of bridging the assets out of Karura back to Kusama.

How can I go about withdrawing the KSM tokens directly without having to use the Karura graphical interface?

[image: Karura Bridge UI]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can withdraw the assets by submitting an XCM extrinsic directly to the Karura parachain (this applies to any parachain that uses the `xtokens` pallet: [xtokens](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/tree/master/xtokens)).

This can be done from the command line, but the easier way is to use the Polkadot.js interface for the relevant parachain, the Karura interface can be found here: [Karura - Extrinsics](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkarura-rpc-0.aca-api.network#/extrinsics).

An example of an `xToken` transfer in a JSON format looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    name: "currency_id",
    type: "acala_primitives:currency:CurrencyId",
    type_name: "CurrencyId",
    value: {
      Token: "KSM"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "amount",
    type: "U128",
    type_name: "Balance",
    value: "123400000000"
  },
  {
    name: "dest",
    type: "xcm:VersionedMultiLocation",
    type_name: "Box<VersionedMultiLocation>",
    value: {
      V1: {
        interior: {
          X1: {
            AccountId32: {
              id: "0x46ebddef8cd9bb167dc30878d7113b7e168e6f0646beffd77d69d39bad76b47a",
              network: {
                Any: null
              }
            }
          }
        },
        parents: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "dest_weight",
    type: "U64",
    type_name: "Weight",
    value: 5000000000
  }
]
```

**Arg 1:** `currency_id` defines the token you want to transfer - in our case it's `KSM`.

**Arg 2:** `amount` defines the amount of tokens you want to transfer - this value uses base units so 1 KSM is 1000000000000 in base units - in our case 123400000000 is equal to 0.1234 KSM

**Arg 3:** `dest` defines the destination address to which we want to send the tokens - note that this is the 32 byte account ID and not the SS58 address format (you can get the account ID from an address using the `subkey inspect <SS58>` command in the terminal).

**Note:** The parent junctions parameter `parents` should be set to `1` as we are sending the funds to an external address on the relay chain (i.e. 1 level up in the consensus hierarchy).

**Arg 4:** `dest_weight` defines the weight for XCM execution on the destination chain - here we set a constant of 5000000000.

Using the Polkadot.js interface we can fill out the `xTokens.transfer()` extrinsic information like so:

[image: Extrinsics interface]

We can then submit the transaction and the KSM tokens should be transferred from Karura to Kusama when the transaction is included in the chain.

Comment: I think you should mention that the `parents` field of the destination MUST be 1, otherwise it stays at 0 and it gets sent back to your own account.

Comment: @KeithYeung Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Your note is still a bit inaccurate -- the reason why you must set the `parents` parameter to 1 is because you are specifically sending funds to an account on the relay chain, and `parents: 1` signifies the location that's "one level up" from the Karura parachain, i.e. the Kusama relay chain.

Comment: orml-xtokens is some high level xcm wrapper, maybe better to use some low level `InitRerserveWithDraw` primitives to demonstrate and `parents: 1` is just the destination from the view of parachain but not the canonical repensentation for KSM in relaychain which should be `parents:0,Here` instead

Comment: If you have an example with lower-level XCM primitives it would be interesting to see - feel free to create another answer.

Comment: @Ron It is *highly* inadvisable to craft raw XCM instructions on your own and send/execute it, due to the amount of complexity involved with XCM in general, and will very easily result in a loss of funds if even one parametric detail was overlooked or configured wrongly.

Comment: did not test it yet, should be something like [this](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/9e041dc9d213f843b18b3008f32f3acabb287dcb/xtokens/src/lib.rs#L634-L644) and worthy to note that the fee asset in `buy_execution` should be the canonical repensentation for KSM in relaychain as `parents:0` but not `parent:1` in parachain. agree with what @KeithYeung mentioned here, just want to add some more details for what is hidden under the hood

Comment: @Ron No, there is no "canonical representation" of a `MultiLocation`. Every `MultiLocation` is relative and must be understood under the context of the interpreting consensus system, i.e. if I am on Karura, then the `MultiLocation` of `junctions: Here, parents: 1` represents the location of Kusama, whereas if I'm in Kusama, `Here` is enough to represent KSM.